# How to show a SwiftUI View programmatically without a button

Tags: ios, view, swiftui

I have a problem right now:
What I want: The first time the app starts my already existing view should be presented. I already implemented something in the AppDelegate that checks if the app launched for the first time. And if thats the case another view should be presented. Is there a method to do this directly in the AppDelegate like it was possible with Storyboards?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your AppDelegate you have a **hosting controller** that bootstraps the main SwiftUI view. So one way to achieve this is to conditionally set the `rootView`.

```
UIHostingController(rootView: isFirstTime ? FirstTimeView() : ContentView())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create an initial `RootView` that merely switches between content and provides an `EnvironmentValues` that's passed to it.

```swift
struct RootView: View {
  @Environment(\.isInitialLaunch) var isInitialLaunch: Bool

  var body: some View {
    Group {
      if isInitialLaunch {
        FirstTimeView()
      } else {
        ContentView()
      }
  }
}
```

Then, in `SceneDelegate`:

```swift
self.window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: RootView().environment(\.isInitialLaunch, isInitialLaunch))
```

Or, make `isInitialLaunch` a `@State` (or `@Binding`, `@ObservedObject`, etc.) variable. This way, after your onboarding process, if you change it to `false`, SwiftUI will actually automatically animate users to the `ContentView`.